# "cutoff" in an integral

Tags: перевод, математика, физика

Sometimes when physicists compute an integral (EDIT: in quantum field theory), they introduce what is called a "cutoff", which means an infinite bound in the integral is replaced by a finite parameter, calculations are made, and then the parameter that was introduced as a bound in the integral is taken out to infinity. My question is: how do you say "cutoff" in Russian in this context?

I guess the answer might be some prefixed form of сечение, but I was not successful in figuring this out from a web search. (I did discover in this way that катофф has been borrowed into Russian for use in poker, which must be of more recent vintage that the need to say "cutoff" in physics.)

Edit: If answers can be supported by pointing to a place where the translated term is used in a physics computational context, and which I might find without too much trouble, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, I properly understand what you are talking about. About solving an _несобственный интеграл второго рода_ (improper intergral of the second kind) i. e. `\int_a^b f(x) dx` where `f(x) \to \pm\infty` in `x = a` or `x = b`?

Comment: More or less, but procedurally we start with an integral over the whole real line or all of space, and figure it out by introducing a cutoff parameter L, integrate over |x| \leq L, and then at the end let L tend to infinity.

Comment: Got an idea then. Usually such an integral has "бесконечный предел интегрирования", so in such cnotext you can say that you use/introduce "конечный предел (интегрирования) L" which you then tend to infinity. At least, I can imagine myself writing something like this.

Comment: I'm not looking for a word or phrase that will just happen to make sense, but rather the term that physicists really use.

Comment: I just so happen to have been educated in solid state physics. Can look it up in papers if you have some specific area the article addresses. To be honest, I do not remember there being any specific term used in such situation. Cannot speak for theoretical physicists, though.

Comment: @KCd The problem is that I can’t google much usage of _cutoff_ in English. Can you provide some real examples in the context?

Comment: @KCd In the meantime, let us consider a simple example: `\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx` = `\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}` = `\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \arcsin (1-\epsilon)` = `\pi / 2`. Is there something that may be called a _cutoff_?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd really like to know what term is used by practicing physicists. On the Russian wikipedia page for regularizaton (in physics), which I just looked at, I find the term регуляризационный параметр. Maybe that's the answer. I do find this used on http://igorivanov.blogspot.ru/2009/07/delta-2d-3.html.

Comment: @KCd I’d like to repeat that some English examples from you would be much more useful.

Comment: @KCd Unfortunately not qualified in the field to give much advice.:( Still, looking at the examples I am inclined to think this use is restricted to the use in quantum field theory and is not a universal term for calculating integrals in general. Moreover, the English articles on regularisation correspond to the explanation I see in Russian and don't use any "cutoff".

Comment: _Регулирующий параметр_: [Регуляризация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29)

Comment: But it seems _регуляризационный параметр_ is widely used

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: I find googling cutoff integral physics gives numerous examples of this usage, e.g., http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/power-counting-with-a-cutoff, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_%28physics%29, and page 27 of http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnCardy/qft/qftcomplete.pdf.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: did those links to English examples help you?

Comment: @KCd Oh! Thanks for reminding me. I’ve post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @DmitryAlexandrov: did those links to English examples help you?

Yes, they helped of course. I’ve googled around the Web and made sure that @vix2 is absolutely right: *cutoff* as a verb would be *обрезать*, as a noun – *обрезание*, though you may think that the latter sounds a bit funny (most common meaning of *обрезание* is *circumcision* :-). You can found it both in books / articles, e. g.:

> Чтобы придать смысл расходящимся фейнмановским интегралам, вводится
>   некоторая промежуточная регуляризация (ультрафиолетовое обрезание Λ).
>   [[A. A. Славнов. Симметрии и перенормировка]](http://www1.jinr.ru/Archive/Pepan/2003-v34/v-34-7/pdf_obzory/v34p7_01.pdf)
>
> Поэтому любое ковариантоное обрезание (такое, как в методе Фейнмана) будет автоматически гарантировать исчезновение собственного натяжения...
>   [[С. Швебер. Введение в релятивистскую квантовую теорию поля]](http://books.google.ru/books?id=iEf5AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA497&ots=vjCcjgrFjT&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%20%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD&hl=ru&pg=PA497#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%20%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD&f=false)

...and at least in one dictionary:

> инфракрасное обрезание (ктп) — infrared cutoff
>   ультрафиолетовое обрезание (ктп) — ultraviolet cutoff
>   (‘ктп’ stands for *квантовая теория поля*)
>   [V. D. Novikov et al. The Russian-English Dictionary of Physics. — RUSSO, 2004]

However, I am still not sure that term is used enough widely since a) there are too few occurences in google; b) somewhere it is explained in parentheses via English *cutoff*.

> Таким образом, это соотношение показывает что величину инфракрасного обрезания (IR cutoff) нельзя выбирать независимо от величины ультрафиолетового обрезания.
>   [[Ускоренное расширение вселенной и голографический принцип]](http://www.modcos.com/articles.php?id=25)

But maybe the reason is that too few Russian quantum field theorist write in Russian or publish their preprints in the Internet.

Finally, may I ask why you need this?

Comment: My interest was largely just curiosity, actually.

Comment: I've looked up the stress on обрезание at gramota.ru and it says both обрЕзание and обрезАние are used. Do they have the same meaning, or is one stress usage the religious ritual and the other is everything else with the meaning of cutoff?

Comment: @KCd That’s a good question. I always mark stressed syllables in discussing words here on R.SE, but now I’m just not sure. Common pronunciation is _обреза́ние_ of course (as a proof see ‘Русское словесное ударение’ by Зарва), but there are quite a lot of professional dialectisms which differ from common words by stress. Since I had never heard _обрезание_ in that context, I did not want to mislead you. But definitely there would be nothing wrong to say _обреза́ние_.

Comment: @KCd Verbs _обре́зать_ / _обреза́ть_ are different grammatical forms: perfective and imperfective respectively. You know it, of course.

Comment: @KCd You’d better ask vix2. He seems to be more familiar with QFT.

Answer (score 4):

"Интеграл **обрезается** на высоких частотах в связи с конечными "
"Интеграл **обрезается** на дебаевской моде"
etc.

Comment: Где ударение в слове обрезание, когда оно используется в физике?

Comment: Интеграл обр`езан, интеграл обрез'ается.

Comment: Спасибо, но я имел в виду обрезание: в физике оно обре́зание или обреза́ние?

Answer (score 0):

**"отсечка"** works fine, I'd say there is not a good word for this concept for everyday use but  "отсечка" works even if it sounds a bit like professional slang. The important thing is, you are going to be understood because this word means just that: some threshold after which you say "OK, enough, stop that and don't go any further"

In audio recording context I use *"обрезание"*  for cutoff/clipping. When you are recording a signal that is too loud you don't actually *want* it to be cut off. Still the peaks get limited (note that I do not do this for life, just record now and then). So here rather than limiting value to a reasonable value you lose information by trimming the peaks of a signal.

"Сечение" means "section" (eg. conical section) and is a term with a completely different meaning: something you get when dissecting something else with a surface (often planar).

UPD: from a lecture [here at page 12](http://ums.physics.usu.ru/st/NUM_03.PDF)

> Интегрирование **обрывается** на некотором значении *x = b*...

Comment: Concerning your last remark, I had said that perhaps a prefixed form of сечение, not that word itself, might fit. For example, in math there is a concept called "truncated Witt vector", which in Russian is усеченный вектор Витта. Though in English the terms truncation and cutoff and not interchangeable in practice, so maybe it doesn't work that way in Russian (or maybe it does).

Comment: Aah, regrading the regularisation parameter, it seems I thought too much into these. I have just re-read the article carefully. Basically, in quantum theory you call that Λ a *regularization parameter* because it is, well, a parameter which you use to perform regularization required to make a meaningful answer out of your divergent integrals. If what you do with your integral is not regularization then, naturally, there is no regularization parameter (just as you do not call any multiplier a "normalization constant" if you do not actually normalize anything)

Answer (score 0):

The most acceptable translation for *Cut-off point* would be *точка отсечения*. However, in the case it is common to say *пренебрегаем вкладом в интеграл значений `x > y`, поскольку [proof that ignored part is indeed small enough to be ignored].*

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for is **Предел**.

There is a wiki page about integrals: [Определенный интеграл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB).

You can see there terms *нижний предел* and *верхний предел* meaning *lower cutoff* and *upper cutoff* respectively.

Comment: Вы определенно невнимательно прочитали дискуссию в комментариях под вопросом. Да и сам вопрос, пожалуй, тоже.

Comment: The term предел is not going to fit this context. The terms нижний предел and верхний предел for definite integrals are translated as lower bound and upper bound.